# Как сделать выпадающее окно поверх текста?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть кнопка button. Под ней текст. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на нее плавно выпадало окно drop поверх этого текста, не отодвигая его вниз, а при отведении исчезало.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотрите в сторону position: absolute и z-index

Comment: Нужно, чтобы на разных экранах не съезжало окно. А position absolute этого не позволит

Comment: @ArturHan, чтоб куда не съезжало? Вы можете пояснить?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('.wnd').show(400)
})

$('.btn').on('mouseout', function(){
  $('.wnd').hide(400)
})
```

```css
.wnd {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  padding:5px;
  background:#fff;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn">Я кнопка</button>
    <div class="wnd">А я всплывающее окно</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Привет, я текст под кнопкой
  </div>
  


</div>
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы на разных экранах не съезжало окно

Comment: Что такое "не съезжало окно"?

Comment: Отображалось строго под кнопкой

Comment: так оно и будет под кнопкой, если у их общего родительского блока задано position: relative

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-нибудь так сделать, например (без js):

```css
.drop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.drop p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
button:hover ~ .drop {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>
Кнопка
</button>
<div class="drop">
<p>
Дроп</p>
</div>
<p>
Тут какой-то текст
</p>
```

Comment: Нужно, чтобы на разных экранах не съезжало окно

Comment: @ArturHan, в смысле - "не съезжало окно"?

Comment: Не очень понимаю что вы имеете в виду, но на всякий случай скажу, что абсолютное позиционирование происходит относительно родительского элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Мне вот эта реализация по душе. На чистом css+html5

```css
/* Стили модального окна */
.modal-header h2 {
    color: #555;  
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;    
    margin: 0;
}
/* кнопка закрытия окна */
.modal .btn-close {
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
.modal .btn-close:hover {
    color: red;
}
/* слой затемнения */
.modal-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}
.modal-overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 102;
}
/* активация слоя затемнения и модального блока */
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap:before,
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-overlay {
    display: block;
}
.modal-open:checked ~ .modal-wrap .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 20%;
}
/* элементы модального окна */
.modal-dialog {
    background: #fefefe;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
    z-index: 103;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.modal-body p {
    margin: 0;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: #eaeaea solid 1px;
}
.modal-header h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.modal-footer {
    border-top: #eaeaea solid 1px;
    text-align: right;
}
/* адаптивные картинки в модальном блоке */
.modal-body img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/* кнопки */
.btn {
    background: #fff;
    border: #555 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.btn-primary {
    background: #428bca;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-primary:hover{
    background: #66A1D3;
}
```

```html
<!-- Кнопка активации -->
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">Открыть</label>
<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal">
  <input class="modal-open" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" hidden>
  <div class="modal-wrap" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <label class="modal-overlay" for="modal-1"></label>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Заголовок </h2>
        <label class="btn-close" for="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">×</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Здесь размещаете любое содержание...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" for="modal-1">Отлично!</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто, но не соответствует заданию.

Comment: Круто, но выпадать должно по наведению, а не по клику